# how to find file and size in linux

Tags: linux, redhat

I have to do this task on linux

find recursively only files in /etc that are larger than 200kb and redirect stdout to a file named FLfindout and redirect stderr to a file named FLfinderr

and I typed in

```
find /etc 200k > FLfindout 2> FLstderr
```

and I don't know what the output suppose to be look like. and is this command right?

Comment: `cat FLfindout` and see what you have (it will be empty or not created) as you need to use the size flag. See [List files bigger than filesize specified](http://superuser.com/questions/233616/list-files-bigger-than-filesize-specified) for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right you just want to get the list of files greater than 200Kb, you can try

find /etc -type f -size +200

if you want this print into a file, you could try

find /etc -type f -size +200 > file.txt

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 find /etc -type f -size +200k  -print > FLfindout 2> FLstderr
```

Comment: I was wondering what is -type f mean?

Comment: `-type f `  means type of file is  a regular file